# Multi User Application - Using Excel, Access and Sharepoint

Tags: excel, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, ms-access-2010, vba

I have to create a multi user application, in which as per the parameters provided by user a report will be published in excel format. I need some help in figuring out that whether an integration of excel, ms access and sharepoint is possible? Something like -  I can keep all my data in ms access and put an excel in sharepoint so that all the user can use it. Parameters selected by users will go and fetch data in ms access and then publish data and on the basis of that pivots will also be created.

Kindly let me know if something like this possbile and if it then what all steps i have to follow and what can be the challenges
Thanks

Comment: Why do you say that "Macros will not work on sharepoint excel"?  I have lots of macro enabled (.xlsb/m) files on SharePoint and they are fully functional.

Comment: @MarkFitzgerald -  today i linked the excel file with ms access table and uploaded that excel sheet on sharepoint. When i asked my colleague to download the same excel sheet and try to refresh the data on this system, he was unable to do.